# f-divergence vs Jensen-Shannon divergence

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

What are the main differences between ① [f-divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-divergence), and ② [Jensen-Shannon divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%E2%80%93Shannon_divergence)? What are the use cases?

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_distance#Examples

Comment: The $f$-divergence is a *family* of divergences of which Jensen-Shannon is one such type.

Comment: @DavidKraemer, according to the reference above, it seems like $f$-divergence doesn't include JS divergence.

Comment: See the [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-divergence#Instances_of_f-divergences).

Comment: Thanks. This is what I thought.
The reference I used is confusing.